# Deleting '.status' file associated with azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell

Is there any way (Azure Powershell command) to delete '.status' file associated with an azure virtual machine.

Remove-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $CloudServiceName -Slot Production -DeleteVHD

The cmdlet above provides a way to delete the associated vhd but '.status' file is not deleted.
I cannot delete by going to azure portal and deleting them one by one. it would take a long time and a very large number of mouse clicks which seems to be useless and tiring in my specific case.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can do it with Storage Explorer. Find the container and just delete the file.

Comment: yes, but actually i am already using a powershell script to delete a the associated vhd once a virtual machine is deleted. so i was looking for a solution where i could find some sort of PS script or commandlet (e.g.  something like-deletevhd flag)  which would let me delete the associated '.status' file and in bulk as well. there are thousands of such files in my storage container, i cant delete the container as some vhd's and status files are still attached with some virtual machines and deleting them one by one through a GUI feels so tiring and time consuming as well